# How to get pyodbc connection on AWS MWAA Airflow DAG?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, airflow, pyodbc, mwaa

I tried to put in requirements.txt for `MWAA Airflow` with `pyodbc=4.0.30` and in code, made connection string like

```
dbconnection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server="+Server+";Database="+Database+";UID="+UserID+";PWD="+Password, autocommit=True)
```

Now the error is `Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/test.py] No module named 'pyodbc'`

*Version of Airflow: 1.10.12*

There is hardly any documentation on `SQL Server/ Postgres` based connection on `MWAA AWS` documentation, especially for `pyodbc` connection, I earlier got this issue with `lambda functions` and figured it out with `lambda layers`, but not sure how `MWAA` works, any suggestions appreciated.

*Please don't recommend any other technology like EC2 to host Airflow as the company is very rigid to use MWAA Airflow.*

Comment: It seems like you are trying to work with pyodbc directly. In that case this is just like any other python package in your code. Not really Airflow or mwaa related? In Airflow if you want to use ODBC you should install 
ODBC provider https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-odbc and use OdbcHook - The hook works with ODBC connection that you will define in Admin -> Connections.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(
            server=server,
            user=username,
            password=password,
            database=database
        )
query ="select IDpk,name,Remarks from TestTable"
df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-sql-server.html